# Every holomorphic vector bundle on a stein manifold is Nakano positive?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, holomorphic-bundles

I encounter this statement on page 53 of Takeo Ohsawa's *L2 Approaches in Several Complex Variables* but I don't know how to prove it. Could anyone explain it to me or give me a reference for it?